# SQL - How do I delete two entities referencing each other

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints

So I have two entities referencing each other, `parent`, `child`.

`child` must be deleted if `parent` is deleted, but cannot be deleted while there's still a `parent` referencing it.

These are the two constraints I've been given:

```sql
ALTER TABLE public.parent
  ADD CONSTRAINT parent__child_id__fk
    FOREIGN KEY (child_id) REFERENCES child(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
;

ALTER TABLE public.child
  ADD CONSTRAINT child__parent_code__id__fk
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_code, id) REFERENCES parent(code, child_id)
      ON UPDATE CASCADE
      ON DELETE RESTRICT
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
;
```

I now want to delete a `parent` (and the corresponding `child`) ...

```
SQL Error [23503]:
ERROR: update or delete on table "parent" violates foreign key constraint
"child__parent_code__id__fk" on table "child"

    Detail: Key (code, child_id)=(A0B7EBF6-3_DELETE_ME, 10)
            is still referenced from table "child".
```

Whoop-dee-doo ...

Yes, it's referenced by the bloody entry I'm trying to delete...

(which I know because there's a unique constraint on `parent.code`)

Looks like I CAN delete the entry if I set the `child`'s fk to `ON DELETE CASCADE`, but that doesn't seem to be what the guy breathing down my neck wants, which is "if you delete a `parent` delete its `child`, too, if you delete a `child` that has a `parent`, DON'T".

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you post the complete DLL for the two tables?

Comment: Why the FK constraint on `child` table is 2-column, including `child_id`? Couldn't it be just `FOREIGN KEY (parent_code) REFERENCES parent(code)`?

Comment: @PeterHe Can't. Proprietory and way too big for this question.

Comment: @jbet Because there are more than one `child` entities that have their own table and the `parent`'s code needs be unique across all of them (whereas the `child`'s ID is unique only within its own table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete from both tables in one statement using a CTE:

```
WITH x AS (
    DELETE FROM parent
    WHERE ...
    RETURNING id
)
DELETE FROM child
WHERE ...;
```