# How do I rewrite `WITH` to JPQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jpql, spring-repositories

So [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479792/sql-how-do-i-delete-two-entities-referencing-each-other) resulted in an elegant solution:

```
WITH a AS (
   DELETE FROM Alpha 
   WHERE code LIKE '%DELETE%' 
     AND beta_id NOTNULL 
   RETURNING code
)
DELETE FROM Beta b 
WHERE b.alpha_code IN (SELECT code FROM a);
```

Works perfectly...
with the caveat that I'm not allowed to use it. -.-

Because we're using Spring JPA and I'm not supposed to use native queries if I can avoid it.

How do you rewrite this into something that can eventually be put into an `@Query` without making it native?

```
DELETE FROM Beta
    WHERE alpha_code IN (
            DELETE FROM alpha
                WHERE code LIKE '%DELETE%'
                AND beta_id NOTNULL
            RETURNING code
    )
;
```

results in `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM"`.

Note: the point of the answer is having to delete entries from both, `Alpha` and `Beta` in the same query.

Comment: I doubt you can do anything remotely advanced like that with JPQ (you probably can't even using a single table `delete` with the `returning` clause). You will have to split this up into multiple statements. First you need to collect the values from `alpha.code` store them somewhere (1st statement), then delete the rows in `alpha` (2nd statement) then use the values you kept in memory to delete the rows in `beta` (3rd statement)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The problem IS, I cannot split it up into multiple statements, because if I do, database constraints will throw an exception. -.-

Comment: Then you have to use a native query.